# LEFT JOIN 4 tables but show multiple value

Tags: mysql, left-join

i have 4 tables, and some of them have more than 1 value. What i need is sum but current query show duplication

table 1 tb_satker

```
kode_satker     nama_satker
412772  KANTOR PUSAT DITJEN HUBLA
412781  OP UTAMA TANJUNG PRIOK
412797  KSOP SUNDA KELAPA
413422  KESYAHBANDARAN UTAMA TANJUNG PRIOK
606301  BALAI KESEHATAN KERJA PELAYARAN
652474  KSOP KEPULAUAN SERIBU
652481  KSOP MUARA BARU
652495  KSOP MUARA KARANG
652500  KSOP KALIBARU
652517  KSOP MARUNDA
```

Table 2 tb_target

```
id  kode_satker     jumlah
1   412772  500
```

Table 3 tb_simponi

```
id  kode_satker     jumlah
1   412772  100
2   412772  200
```

Table 4 tb_pagu

```
id  kode_satker     sumber  jumlah
1   412772  D   1
2   412772  D   2
```

What i have done is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93c7ac/1

```
SELECT
    tb_satker.nama_satker,
    tb_target.jumlah as target,
    sum(tb_simponi.jumlah) as realisasi,
    sum(tb_pagu.jumlah) as pagu
FROM tb_satker
LEFT JOIN tb_target
    ON tb_satker.kode_satker = tb_target.kode_satker
LEFT JOIN tb_simponi
    ON tb_satker.kode_satker = tb_simponi.kode_satker
LEFT JOIN tb_pagu
    ON tb_satker.kode_satker = tb_pagu.kode_satker
GROUP BY
    tb_satker.kode_satker
```

But it show

```
nama_satker     target  realisasi   pagu
KANTOR PUSAT DITJEN HUBLA   500     600     6
OP UTAMA TANJUNG PRIOK  (null)  (null)  (null)
KSOP SUNDA KELAPA   (null)  (null)  (null)
KESYAHBANDARAN UTAMA TANJUNG PRIOK  (null)  (null)  (null)
BALAI KESEHATAN KERJA PELAYARAN     (null)  (null)  (null)
KSOP KEPULAUAN SERIBU   (null)  (null)  (null)
KSOP MUARA BARU     (null)  (null)  (null)
KSOP MUARA KARANG   (null)  (null)  (null)
KSOP KALIBARU   (null)  (null)  (null)
KSOP MARUNDA    (null)  (null)  (null)
```

I Expect the result show

```
nama_satker     target  realisasi   pagu
KANTOR PUSAT DITJEN HUBLA   500     300     3
OP UTAMA TANJUNG PRIOK  (null)  (null)  (null)
KSOP SUNDA KELAPA   (null)  (null)  (null)
KESYAHBANDARAN UTAMA TANJUNG PRIOK  (null)  (null)  (null)
BALAI KESEHATAN KERJA PELAYARAN     (null)  (null)  (null)
KSOP KEPULAUAN SERIBU   (null)  (null)  (null)
KSOP MUARA BARU     (null)  (null)  (null)
KSOP MUARA KARANG   (null)  (null)  (null)
KSOP KALIBARU   (null)  (null)  (null)
KSOP MARUNDA    (null)  (null)  (null)
```

Comment: Please stop SHOUTING your question title. It's not necessary to SHOUT. If someone can help, they will help. There's no need to raise your voice to get attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common mistake folks seem to make here when learning about joins is that it can cause aggregations to not give the expected results.  In your case, it looks like some rows are being overcounted, probably due to joins.  One workaround is to perform the aggregations in separate subqueries.

```
SELECT
    t1.nama_satker,
    t2.jumlah AS target,
    COALESCE(t3.realisasi, 0) AS realisasi,
    COALESCE(t4.pagu, 0) AS pagu
FROM tb_satker t1
LEFT JOIN tb_target t2
    ON t1.kode_satker = t2.kode_satker
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT kode_satker, SUM(jumlah) AS realisasi
    FROM tb_simponi
    GROUP BY kode_satker
) t3
    ON t1.kode_satker = t3.kode_satker
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT kode_satker, SUM(jumlah) AS pagu
    FROM tb_pagu
    GROUP BY kode_satker
) t4
    ON t1.kode_satker = t4.kode_satker;
```

Note that your `GROUP BY` syntax also had problems; you were aggregating by one column but selecting other non aggregate columns, which does not make logical sense.  In the refactored version above, this is not an issue, since we don't need to use `GROUP BY` anymore on the outer query.